# WS-AT Protocol question

Tags: wcf, transactions, integration

Could you help me with understanding how does WS-AT protocols works. My question is: how does client server get to know url to WS-AT coordination services?

Answer (score 1):

WS-AT is handled by the mechanism that handles web services on your system. For instance, if you use .NET on Windows, then WS-AT is handled by WCF, which uses Windows' Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) to coordinate transactions. For this apparently it also relies on the WS-Coordination protocol.

You do need to configure your system for WS-AT. On Windows systems, you would use the WS-AT Config Utility for this (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732007.aspx).

See also the WS-AT Specs at http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os.html and the WS-COOR Specs at http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wscoor/2006/06.

Further reading: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/WS-AtomicTransaction.

Be aware, though, that implementing WS-AT is no easy task and that effectively coordinating transactions over heterogeneous systems takes a long time (and therefore you need to configure your systems for long timeouts).

Comment: Thanks for answer. For instance, if we are talking about communication between Java client and WCF service. How Java client get to know address of coordinator? I didn't find any references in wsdl.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the coordination the client (or probably more accurately / likely a controlling service)starts a transaction using it local transaction technology (MSDTC in the case of WCF). When a request is made to another service a WS-Coordination header is sent in the message with identifying the coordination type as WS-AT, a coordination ID (Transaction ID) and with the address of the coordinator (in this case MSDTC)

Answer (score 0):

Generally transaction coordinator is at client side. When the client invokes a transactional web service it must include a SOAP header like this:

```
<wscoor:CoordinationContext
    xmlns:wscoor="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wscoor/2006/06"
    SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wscoor:Identifier>urn:0:ffffac1b0a40:46142b39:57ce82aa:1f57
    </wscoor:Identifier>
    <wscoor:CoordinationType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wsat/2006/06
    </wscoor:CoordinationType>
    <wscoor:RegistrationService>
        <wsa:Address>http://xxxx.yyyy.zz:8080/ws-c11/RegistrationService
        </wsa:Address>
        <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
            <wsarj:InstanceIdentifier
                xmlns:wsarj="http://schemas.arjuna.com/ws/2005/10/wsarj">0:ffffac1b0a40:46142b39:57ce82aa:1f57
            </wsarj:InstanceIdentifier>
        </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <wsa:Metadata>
            <wsam:ServiceName xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
                EndpointName="RegistrationPortType">wscoor:RegistrationService</wsam:ServiceName>
        </wsa:Metadata>
    </wscoor:RegistrationService>
</wscoor:CoordinationContext>
```

At `<wsa:Address>` it specifies the URL of the transaction coordinator registration service.